# Have constraints such that foreign key is in table 1 is not foreign key in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a table Property, now there are two tables Rent and sale, each having property_id as the foreign key. How can I assure that whatever property_id is in Rent must not be repeated in sale? If it does MySQL should throw an error.

This is the Rent Table, exactly similar is Sale

```
CREATE TABLE Rent
(
  /*some data*/
  Property_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Property_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Property_id) REFERENCES Property(Property_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single table with a discriminator column

Example

```
CREATE TABLE property (
    id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    /* some data */
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE contract (
    id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    property_id INT NOT NULL,
    type        VARCHAR(32) CHECK ( type IN ('rent', 'sale') ),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES property(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Rent (
    id            INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    /* some data */
    contract_id   INT NOT NULL,
    contract_type VARCHAR(32) CHECK ( contract_type = 'rent'),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (contract_id)
        REFERENCES contact(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Sale (
    id            INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    /* some data */
    contract_id   INT NOT NULL,
    contract_type VARCHAR(32) CHECK ( contract_type = 'sale'),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (contract_id)
        REFERENCES contact(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: What would be a better option, to have a separate table contract or have a contract column type inside the Property table?

Comment: Both could work. It really depends on your data model. I would probably prefer the contract table for most use cases though.